# Combining modules fails

Tags: elm

I want to connect all the models but I always get those **cycle-errors**.

My whole `model` looks like this:

```
type alias Model =
    { users : List User
    , blogs : List Blog
    , posts : List Post
    , comments : List Comment
    , labels : List Label
    }
```

Sadly there appears the `error` message:

```
Your module imports form a cycle:
  
  ┌─────┐
  │    Features.User
  │     ↓
  │    Features.Blog
  │     ↓
  │    Features.Label
  │     ↓
  │    Features.Post
  │     ↓
  │    Features.Comment
  └─────┘
```

This is the `user` file:

```
module Features.User exposing (..)

import Features.Blog as Blog
import Features.Comment as Comment
import Features.Post as Post


type alias Id =
    String


type alias User =
    { id : String
    , name : String
    , email : String
    , password : String
    , blogs : List Blog.Id
    , posts : List Post.Id
    , comments : List Comment.Id
    }
```

I would love to get some input how to restructure the code so that it works just fine. Thanks.

Comment: You probably need to add some more details to your question. It's uncertain how have you managed to get this circular reference. For example what are the links apart from User module. Even better if you can provide a minimal working example, i.e. a toy application that shows only the references.

Comment: You could put all the type definitions in a single file to avoid this, but looking solely at the type names I get impression you be storing duplicate data in your state - e.g. a user who has a blog, and a user has made a comment. For example, perhaps your comments could just contain the id of the user, and then you look that up in a Users Dict when you need it?